# Using bootstrap on page with resizable left panel

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter bootstrap on a page witch is split into two parts - left panel and main window. When the panel changes its width, I want the layout of the main window behave as the page viewport has changed.

Is it possible to change bootstrap breakpoints with javascript, so when I change the left panel, the main window starts using col-xs instead of col-md?

Edit: 
In the other words: I need to change layout according to some container, not to the browser window width.

Comment: In bootstrap you can define multiple "col" classes on a tag. One for each breakpoint if you like.

Comment: Or you can set breakpoints by media queries in your css, replacing bootstrap breakpoints